# How can I get BpM and SpO2 with MAX30102 in a coordinated way of coding?

Tags: sensors, arduino-ide, arduino-c++, proximitysensor

I'm trying to write a code for getting HeartRate and SpO2 readings and I'm using MAX30102 sensor. With MAX30100 we can get bot in a direct function:

```
pox.getHeartRate() \\ for getting heart rate
pox.getSpO2() \\ for getting oxygen saturation
```

In the MAX3010x library, there are those examples for Heart rate and SpO2, but the code is large in both and I want one code to display both. I'm a beginner I don't know what part of the code is important and what I can get rid of. I'm afraid of memory issues and code complexity.

This is the code example of heart rate:

```c
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30105.h"

#include "heartRate.h"

MAX30105 particleSensor;

const byte RATE_SIZE = 4; //Increase this for more averaging. 4 is good.
byte rates[RATE_SIZE]; //Array of heart rates
byte rateSpot = 0;
long lastBeat = 0; //Time at which the last beat occurred

float beatsPerMinute;
int beatAvg;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Initializing...");

  // Initialize sensor
  if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)) //Use default I2C port, 400kHz speed
  {
    Serial.println("MAX30105 was not found. Please check wiring/power. ");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Place your index finger on the sensor with steady pressure.");

  particleSensor.setup(); //Configure sensor with default settings
  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeRed(0x0A); //Turn Red LED to low to indicate sensor is running
  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeGreen(0); //Turn off Green LED
}

void loop()
{
  long irValue = particleSensor.getIR();

  if (checkForBeat(irValue) == true)
  {
    //We sensed a beat!
    long delta = millis() - lastBeat;
    lastBeat = millis();

    beatsPerMinute = 60 / (delta / 1000.0);

    if (beatsPerMinute < 255 && beatsPerMinute > 20)
    {
      rates[rateSpot++] = (byte)beatsPerMinute; //Store this reading in the array
      rateSpot %= RATE_SIZE; //Wrap variable

      //Take average of readings
      beatAvg = 0;
      for (byte x = 0 ; x < RATE_SIZE ; x++)
        beatAvg += rates[x];
      beatAvg /= RATE_SIZE;
    }
  }

  Serial.print("IR=");
  Serial.print(irValue);
  Serial.print(", BPM=");
  Serial.print(beatsPerMinute);
  Serial.print(", Avg BPM=");
  Serial.print(beatAvg);

  if (irValue < 50000)
    Serial.print(" No finger?");

  Serial.println();
}
```

and this is the code example of SpO2:

```c
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30105.h"
#include "spo2_algorithm.h"

MAX30105 particleSensor;

#define MAX_BRIGHTNESS 255

#if defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
//Arduino Uno doesn't have enough SRAM to store 100 samples of IR led data and red led data in 32-bit format
//To solve this problem, 16-bit MSB of the sampled data will be truncated. Samples become 16-bit data.
uint16_t irBuffer[100]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint16_t redBuffer[100];  //red LED sensor data
#else
uint32_t irBuffer[100]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint32_t redBuffer[100];  //red LED sensor data
#endif

int32_t bufferLength; //data length
int32_t spo2; //SPO2 value
int8_t validSPO2; //indicator to show if the SPO2 calculation is valid
int32_t heartRate; //heart rate value
int8_t validHeartRate; //indicator to show if the heart rate calculation is valid

byte pulseLED = 11; //Must be on PWM pin
byte readLED = 13; //Blinks with each data read

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200); // initialize serial communication at 115200 bits per second:

  pinMode(pulseLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(readLED, OUTPUT);

  // Initialize sensor
  if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)) //Use default I2C port, 400kHz speed
  {
    Serial.println(F("MAX30105 was not found. Please check wiring/power."));
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println(F("Attach sensor to finger with rubber band. Press any key to start conversion"));
  while (Serial.available() == 0) ; //wait until user presses a key
  Serial.read();

  byte ledBrightness = 60; //Options: 0=Off to 255=50mA
  byte sampleAverage = 4; //Options: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32
  byte ledMode = 2; //Options: 1 = Red only, 2 = Red + IR, 3 = Red + IR + Green
  byte sampleRate = 100; //Options: 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 1600, 3200
  int pulseWidth = 411; //Options: 69, 118, 215, 411
  int adcRange = 4096; //Options: 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384

  particleSensor.setup(ledBrightness, sampleAverage, ledMode, sampleRate, pulseWidth, adcRange); //Configure sensor with these settings
}

void loop()
{
  bufferLength = 100; //buffer length of 100 stores 4 seconds of samples running at 25sps

  //read the first 100 samples, and determine the signal range
  for (byte i = 0 ; i < bufferLength ; i++)
  {
    while (particleSensor.available() == false) //do we have new data?
      particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor for new data

    redBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getRed();
    irBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getIR();
    particleSensor.nextSample(); //We're finished with this sample so move to next sample

    Serial.print(F("red="));
    Serial.print(redBuffer[i], DEC);
    Serial.print(F(", ir="));
    Serial.println(irBuffer[i], DEC);
  }

  //calculate heart rate and SpO2 after first 100 samples (first 4 seconds of samples)
  maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(irBuffer, bufferLength, redBuffer, &spo2, &validSPO2, &heartRate, &validHeartRate);

  //Continuously taking samples from MAX30102.  Heart rate and SpO2 are calculated every 1 second
  while (1)
  {
    //dumping the first 25 sets of samples in the memory and shift the last 75 sets of samples to the top
    for (byte i = 25; i < 100; i++)
    {
      redBuffer[i - 25] = redBuffer[i];
      irBuffer[i - 25] = irBuffer[i];
    }

    //take 25 sets of samples before calculating the heart rate.
    for (byte i = 75; i < 100; i++)
    {
      while (particleSensor.available() == false) //do we have new data?
        particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor for new data

      digitalWrite(readLED, !digitalRead(readLED)); //Blink onboard LED with every data read

      redBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getRed();
      irBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getIR();
      particleSensor.nextSample(); //We're finished with this sample so move to next sample

      //send samples and calculation result to terminal program through UART
      Serial.print(F("red="));
      Serial.print(redBuffer[i], DEC);
      Serial.print(F(", ir="));
      Serial.print(irBuffer[i], DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", HR="));
      Serial.print(heartRate, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", HRvalid="));
      Serial.print(validHeartRate, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", SPO2="));
      Serial.print(spo2, DEC);
```

If someone knows something please help me

Comment: You should tell us what you have tried so far. Have you done any basic google search about your problem? I found this resource in less than 3 seconds upon searching for the MAX30102: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/mircemk/max-30102-heart-rate-monitor-on-16x2-lcd-04ef5a   Have you read the documentation? Please show some minimal effort doing elementary research and come here with succinct questions and we will be happy to help you

Comment: Thanks for the link.. and I did researched and the results are always the same a lot of coding to get one thing.. I want to how to get BpM and SpO2 in a shortened way or a direct function or something like that.. if want to get both in one code the  code will be lagre and not well-formated.. I'm sorry I made the wrong question..  I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, however, it is still unclear what *you* have tried so far. Pasting the two codes is not going to help us much. You are asking us to select what parts from both codes are useful but you should show some minimal effort doing so

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my last comment. The most basic structure of an Arduino code consists of an include section, definitions, your variables declaration/initialization, objects instantiation, setup function, and the main loop.

You must be careful with the implementation of the second code. It declares variables inside the setup and the scope of these variables is restricted to only this function, therefore you cannot use them elsewhere in the code.

Create two functions for each mode (heart_rate and sp02) and call them at regular intervals (every 5 seconds or so)

For your intents and purposes, you code should roughly look like this:

```
// Include section
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30105.h"
#include "spo2_algorithm.h"
#include "heartRate.h"

// Definitions
#define MAX_BRIGHTNESS 255

// Variables declaration
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)

uint16_t irBuffer[100]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint16_t redBuffer[100];  //red LED sensor data
#else
uint32_t irBuffer[100]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint32_t redBuffer[100];  //red LED sensor data
#endif

int32_t bufferLength; //data length
int32_t spo2; //SPO2 value
int8_t validSPO2; //indicator to show if the SPO2 calculation is valid
int32_t heartRate; //heart rate value
int8_t validHeartRate; //indicator to show if the heart rate calculation is valid

byte pulseLED = 11; //Must be on PWM pin
byte readLED = 13; //Blinks with each data read

// Heart rate vars

const byte RATE_SIZE = 4; //Increase this for more averaging. 4 is good.
byte rates[RATE_SIZE]; //Array of heart rates
byte rateSpot = 0;
long lastBeat = 0; //Time at which the last beat occurred

float beatsPerMinute;
int beatAvg;

// sampling times

unsigned long prevHRTime;
unsigned long prevSP02Time;

// Sensor object instantiation
MAX30105 particleSensor;

// Setup
void setup(){

// Initialize serial port and configure your sensor 
 Serial.println("Initializing...");

  // Initialize sensor
  if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)) 
  {
    Serial.println("MAX30105 was not found. Please check wiring/power. ");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Place your index finger on the sensor with steady pressure.");

  particleSensor.setup(); //Configure sensor with default settings
  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeRed(0x0A); //Turn Red LED to low to indicate sensor is running
  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeGreen(0); //Turn off Green LED

  prevHRTime = millis();
  prevSP02Time = millis();
}


// main loop

void loop(){

    unsigned long now = millis();

    if(now - prevHRTime > 5000){
        prevHRTime  = now;

        heart_rate();    // Implementation is below

    }

    if(now - prevSP02Time > 5000){
        prevSP02Time = now;

        sp02();    // I did not implement this, but you get the point

    }   
}


void heart_rate(){

 long irValue = particleSensor.getIR();

  if (checkForBeat(irValue) == true)
  {
    //We sensed a beat!
    long delta = millis() - lastBeat;
    lastBeat = millis();

    beatsPerMinute = 60 / (delta / 1000.0);

    if (beatsPerMinute < 255 && beatsPerMinute > 20)
    {
      rates[rateSpot++] = (byte)beatsPerMinute; //Store this reading in the array
      rateSpot %= RATE_SIZE; //Wrap variable

      //Take average of readings
      beatAvg = 0;
      for (byte x = 0 ; x < RATE_SIZE ; x++)
        beatAvg += rates[x];
      beatAvg /= RATE_SIZE;
    }
  }

  Serial.print("IR=");
  Serial.print(irValue);
  Serial.print(", BPM=");
  Serial.print(beatsPerMinute);
  Serial.print(", Avg BPM=");
  Serial.print(beatAvg);

  if (irValue < 50000)
    Serial.print(" No finger?");

  Serial.println();

}
```

This code is UNTESTED and you will need to verify its validity with your own device.

Answer (score 0):

I got this code for measuring bpm and SpO2 at the same time from some youtube channel.
Link- [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SOTsR1k8-g&ab_channel=HowToElectronics)

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"
 
#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS     1000
 
PulseOximeter pox;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;
 
void onBeatDetected()
{
    Serial.println("Beat!");
}
 
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.print("Initializing pulse oximeter..");
 
    // Initialize the PulseOximeter instance
    // Failures are generally due to an improper I2C wiring, missing power supply
    // or wrong target chip
    if (!pox.begin()) {
        Serial.println("FAILED");
        for(;;);
    } else {
        Serial.println("SUCCESS");
    }
     pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);
 
    // Register a callback for the beat detection
    pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
}
 
void loop()
{
    // Make sure to call update as fast as possible
    pox.update();
    if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
        Serial.print("Heart rate:");
        Serial.print(pox.getHeartRate());
        Serial.print("bpm / SpO2:");
        Serial.print(pox.getSpO2());
        Serial.println("%");
 
        tsLastReport = millis();
    }
}
```